# How to disable jQuery autoloading on Ajax request in Yii?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I'm using the following code to generate an ajax request:

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('teamA', '', EnumController::getTeamOption(), array(
        'empty' => '(Team / Single)',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=> $url,
            'update'=>"#resultA",
            //'data'=>"js:$('#teamA').hide().fadeIn()" 
        )
    )
);
```

In my main layout, I have the following:

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array('jquery.js'=>false);?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap=array('jquery.min.js'=>false);?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Yii is loading jQuery copy out of assets and then -- another copy, directly from Google. I want to use only Google copy and force Yii to not load own copy from assets. How can I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Yii you should never hardcode any javascript information in the main layout.

Yii can determine if a client script (javascript) was already included, but for core scripts (like jquery or jqueryui) you have to modify those packages in your config file.

Open the `main.php` configuration file and add all the js packages you need within the `CClientScript` component (you should add it inside `components`), like this:

```
'clientScript'=>array(
  'packages'=>array(
    'jquery'=>array(
      'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/',
      'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
      'coreScriptPosition'=>CClientScript::POS_HEAD
    ),
    'jquery.ui'=>array(
      'baseUrl'=>'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/',
      'js'=>array('jquery-ui.min.js'),
      'depends'=>array('jquery'),
      'coreScriptPosition'=>CClientScript::POS_BEGIN
    )
  ),
),
```

Then, every time you need jquery just add this before your code:

```
$cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
$cs->registerCoreScript('jquery');
```

Yii will then include jquery (or any other script) only once, even if you call it several times in your code.

Comment: wow! thanks a million...and here i thought i knew something about Yii by now :)

Comment: For other JS files (not those defined as 'core scripts' in the config) you can use isScriptFileRegistered() See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CClientScript#isScriptFileRegistered-detail

Comment: If you use registerScript(File) with POS_READY, you do not have to register jquery manually, it is registered automatically. You have to register jquery-ui manually, however.

Comment: this put jquery right at the end of all include scripts. how do you make it at the top?

Answer (score 6):

Following the instructions from [Yii Special Topics Performance](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance#minimizing-script-files), I made a quick test, and this worked:

At the top of the main layout:

```
<?php
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->scriptMap=array(
    'jquery.js'=>false,
    'jquery.ui.js' => false,
);?>
```

In the `<head>` section of the main layout:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<?php echo CGoogleApi::init(); ?>

<?php echo CHtml::script(
    CGoogleApi::load('jquery','1.7.2') . "\n" .
    CGoogleApi::load('jqueryui','1.8.17') 
); ?>
```

I would actually use the CGoogleApi helper, but the jsapi apparently cannot load jquery versions higher than those in my example! I guess that's slow updating on Google's part, because it doesn't work in a plain file either.

Or maybe the js file was still in your cache?

Comment: thanks! not quite what i was looking for but great to know about  CGoogleApi - where did you see it in the documentation?

Comment: I have the link included in my answer, just scroll down a little. It's official docs, so I guess there are more ways to do it, although e.a.'s answer is cleaner, because it works with the register function.

Comment: `CGoogleApi::load('jquery','1.7.2') . "\n" .` does not exist. how would you load the latest jquery?

Answer (score 2):

**This will work**

```
 <?php     
       $cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
       $cs->scriptMap=array(
         'jquery.js'=>false,
         'jquery.ui.js' => false,
); ?>
```