# Using Yii's Ajax Validation without autoload Jquery

Tags: yii

I want to use [CActiveForm](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm)'s [AjaxValidation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#enableAjaxValidation-detail).

My *layout view file* was like this before enabling AjaxValidation:

```
<html lang="tr-TR" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

As you see i'm calling `jquery` framework on my layout page (because i'm using on every page).

And i decided to use CActiveForm's ajax validation. Firstly enable `enableAjaxValidation` while calling it:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'otel-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>
```

And then uncomment this on my controller

```
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

But i got `$(...).yiiactiveform is not a function` error. When i check source code of page :

As you see, one more jquery library included, too. So there are 2 jquery files on page. Because of this i'm getting error. Next i put something like this for disabling jquery.

```
Yii::app()->clientscript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
```

Now jquery is loading only once. But this result is :

```
<html lang="tr-TR" dir="ltr">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/istanbulcityhotels/assets/cb2686c8/jquery.yiiactiveform.js"></script>
<script src="/istanbulcityhotels/js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
```

**jquery.yiiactiveform.js** calling BEFORE **jquery.js** . It should called AFTER jquery.js.
It confused a bit. What should i do?

**ADDITIONAL**
Yes, i read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445488/how-to-disable-yii-jquery-autoload-on-ajax-request) question because titles' are really similar, but question is**not** same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be including jQuery manually from your layout. Instead of doing this, include it from within your `Controller` base class:

```
public function init() {
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery');
}
```

Don't forget to call `parent::init()` from within your concrete controllers.

Comment: what do you mean with *concrete controllers* ? Sorry for bad English. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Eray: The classes that derive from `Controller`, for example `UserController`. Their `init` function (if you are using one) needs to call `parent::init()` -- this is standard PHP stuff but I mention it because it's important.

Comment: OK now i get it . I just modified my protected/components/Controller.php file . And than  called `parent::init()` on my all Controllers. Working *well*. But doing this and adding `parent::init()` to all controllers is a long way. Is it possible to do this with my configuration file ? FOr example can i use `clientScript` component on my configuration file? So i can register jquery on my configuration file, and it'll be included every page.

Comment: @Eray: No, that's not possible. But consider that you now have a ready-made plan to configure similar things in the future: adding another script everywhere is now one additional line in `Controller`. Overriding this in a concrete controller, or for just a specific action, is now also super easy (it was not possible before).

Answer (score 1):

It seems CActiveForm inserts the scripts before the `title` tag using `CClientScript::POS_HEAD` constant. So a workaround is to add this code

```
<?php
$cs=Yii::app()->clientScript;
$cs->scriptMap=array(
    'jquery.js'=>false
);?>
```

to the top of the main layout file in order stop it from loading  jquery, then put the `title` tag after you load your jquery file

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

This way jquery.yiiactiveform.js will be loaded right after jquery.

Answer (score -2):

just  put  your own jquery on tag title,
just like this:

```
<script src="/istanbulcityhotels/js/jquery.js"></script>
<title>your title</title>
```

Comment: Loading jQuery twice won't solve a thing, see http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/14608-ajaxvalidation-problem/page__view__findpost__p__72800