# Fancybox not working after submitting the parent page

Tags: php, jquery, yii, fancybox

I have two buttons in a page. one for Submitting the page and one for Fancybox. After clicking the Submit button Fancybox is not working. I am using YII model validation on submit button click.

My facybox js is:

```
 $(function(){
$(".various3").fancybox({
'width'             : '75.65%',
'height'            : '100%',
'top'               : '-1020',
'autoScale'         : false,
'autoDimensions'                : false,
'scrolling'                     :'No',
'transitionIn'                  : 'none',
'transitionOut'                 : 'none',
'type'              : 'iframe',
'padding'                       : 0,
'margin'                        : 0,
'onComplete'                    : function(){$('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('#MerchantLocations_location_name').focus();}
    });

});
```

This is my view:

```
<a href="<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('/admin/addlocation/');?>" class="various3 " ><input type="button" class="big-btns-small floatright" value="Add Location"/></a>
```

also at error console of Mozilla "Error: TypeError: t is undefined" is appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed......

Am updated the fancy box to latest version 2.1.4 from 1.3.4

Now what happen is the popup is coming . But div with class 'fancybox-overlay' is coming 2 times . ie first one with popup content and a  another with blank(no content). Since the blank div is coming over the other one.The popup immediately close when i click over popup.

To overcome this the including of fancybox script and style sheet moved to header part of the site(it to view/layout/main.php).

Thanks @schmunk for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with Yii grids and their search functionality it is very likely that in the response of a i.e. search query you get `jQuery` delivered again in the AJAX response.
Then the reinitialization of `jQuery` breaks your existing FancyBox widget.

The quick workaround is to disable jQuery in the `scriptMap` section of your `clientScript` component, see this question for details: [How to disable jQuery autoloading on Ajax request in Yii?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445488/how-to-disable-yii-jquery-autoload-on-ajax-request)

Comment: its not grid page its a page adding and ajax validation is disabled