# Yii captcha never passes the validation even if, right letters are in place

Tags: yii

This is on my model rules:

```
 array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()),
```

This is on my _form:

```
$this->widget('CCaptcha', array('buttonOptions' => array('class' => 'captcha-anchor')));
```

On my accessRules:

```
array('allow','actions'=>array('create','index','view','member', 'captcha'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
),
```

I keep getting,

> "The verification code is incorrect"

no matter what I do.

I'm using AjaxValidation with CActiveForm, and wish to keep using it.

Any clue how to fix this?

Please don't post any link, if you happen to know the answer, please describe it, so we can discuss if in need.

Please note that the captcha image is **displaying** and **reloading**. No issues there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and it return false every time because :

1- I define Get POST in some base controller and i send a ajax request to home controller which extended from base , because i can not call base controller directly so i change ajax request to current controller not home controller for all pages.

2- I hard coded JQuery in my layout so Yii load two JQuery in the Page so it send 2 request , first verified and second fails, i disabled JQuery auto load helping by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445488/how-to-disable-yii-jquery-autoload-on-ajax-request) link.